# Conditional `if()` not working in nested loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I am looping worksheets in two workbooks. If there's a matching worksheet in both books, I am transferring a certain range from one book to the other. (This is commented out below.)

I am also tracking which worksheet is present in one book and not the other (resulting in no transfer) which is where I am having a problem. I am only interested in sheets that contain a "-" and placed my collection within the conditional but sheets that do not contain "-" are still getting added.

I think the issue lies in the outer loop? It doesn't add during inner but when outer comes around again, it triggers the `.add`? So perhaps a better question is, what's the logic for a loop to test for matching worksheets?

```
For Each ws In lastWB.Worksheets

    Set lastWS = ws
    lastName = lastWS.Name

        For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            If InStr(1, s.Name, "-") Then
                If s.Name = lastName And s.Range("C3").Value <> "5860" Then
                    Debug.Print lastName
                    's.Range("C14:O48").Value = lastWS.Range("C14:O48").Value
                Else
                    skippedAct.Add lastName 'still adding sheets that do not contain "-"
                End If
            End If

        Next

Next
```

Comment: Confirm that it's the same hyphen character by checking the ascii value? It should be `Asc("-")` = 45 for a normal hyphen, but could your sheet names contain some other character which would not evaluate True in that `If` statement?

Comment: Interesting, changing to `InStr(1, s.Name, Asc("-") )` shows it's not entering loop at all (if statement fails).

Comment: What happens if you `Debug.Print InStr(1, s.Name, "-")` right before your `If` statement? What values does it give you?

Comment: `InStr(1, s.Name, Asc("-") ) ` is the same as using `InStr(1, s.Name, 45 )`. You would want to copy the '-' from the name of a sheet into a cell and use `=Code()` on it to see if it is 45 or not. (You could also use `Debug.Print ASC("-") in the Immediate window, the key think is to copy the "-" from the name of a tab.

Comment: Using @DavidZemens code below, ascii shows 45 but still failed :/

Comment: @JustinMcCartney just did `code` in cell, also shows 45 XD

Comment: You know what, the two workbooks share many sheet names. The collection may be adding the name from thisworkbook and not lastWB but I can't tell which... how do I set a debug for that hmmm...

Comment: Your loop will have `s` belonging to `ThisWorkbook`.  Debugging `s.Parent.Name` will show you the workbook's name which contains' the sheet `s`.

Comment: I look a little closer at your code, is it really necessary to nest these loops? `For each ws in lastWb ... For each s in ThisWorkbook...`?  I'll have another suggestion in a moment...

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is certainly your improper nested loop. You are adding sheet `lastName` to the collection when the conditional `Instr` returns false. But because you are looping every sheet against every sheet, I think you are getting very unexpected results.

Comment: I don't see why you think this is an improper nested loop. It loops through all sheets in book 1 and for each sheet, it loops through all sheets in book2. This is exactly what they need. There is a bit of inconsistency in the code; setting lastWS and lastName for the first book, but just using .name directly for the 2nd book - but that shouldn't cause any errors.

Comment: Even if you accidentally had both ThisWorkbook and LastWB as the same workbook  - you shouldn't have the issue you are experiencing. Regardless of which workbook and if the two sheet names match... if the sheet name in the current book does not contain a "-" your code should skip the `Debug.Print lastName` block.  hmm... I can't figure out how I would force `Debug.Print lastName` to fire on any worksheet that didn't have a "-" in the name, given this code...

Comment: I think David's idea of a function is great. Eliminates the nested loop that's causing the issue ^_^

Comment: @JustinMcCartney yea, I can't follow the logic of nested loops but clearly something was amiss @_@

Comment: It is using `lastName` every time `lastName` and `s.Name` don't match.  `LastName` might include "-", but if `s.Name` doesn't include "-", it passes to the next step.   You could use `If InStr(1,S.Name, "-") and InStr(1,lastName,"-") Then ` or see my answer below.

Comment: Ahh maybe I do need to test BOTH. Will play with it later. Have more code to add to this XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop may be confusing and I think that is the source of your problem as explained in the comments on OP: You're adding `lastName` to the collection whenever the `Instr` returns `False`, but because you're checking every sheet in `lastWB` against every sheet in `ThisWorkbook`, you're getting unexpected results.

This would be a good place to use a custom function:

```
Function SheetExists(sName as String, wb as Workbook)
'Function which will check the presence of a sheet in a given workbook
Dim ret
On Error Resume Next
Set ret = wb.Worksheets(sName)

SheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Get rid of the nested loop, and just do `For each s in ThisWOrkbook.Worksheets`, like so:

```
   For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If InStr(1, s.Name, "-") Then
            If SheetExists(s.Name, lastWB) And s.Range("C3").Value <> "5860" Then
                s.Range("C14:O48").Value = lastWB.Worksheets(s.Name).Range("C14:O48").Value
            Else
                skippedAct.Add s.Name 'still adding sheets that do not contain "-"
            End If
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: The ascii is showing 45 so I change it to `If InStr(1, s.Name, Chr(45)) > 0 Then` but still failed :/

Comment: Awwww yeaaaaa looks like it worked. Will need to fake some sheets to test further but works for current book in question <33

Comment: Doh. I want to test if a sheet in lastWB is in thisbook. Guess I switch the books in the loop and function yes? Edit: YEP ^_^

Comment: Sounds about right.  I think you've got all the right pieces now is just a matter for you to implement with the right logic (it wasn't immediately clear to me which book should be looped)

Comment: Yea that's my fault. Loops are my weakness XD Now I know a way to circumvent going forward^^

Comment: No worries! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes to look at the problem from a different perspective!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `Instr` function does NOT return a `Boolean` (True/False). Instead, it returns an `Integer` with the placement of the found value. So, try using something like:

`If InStr(1, s.Name, "-") > 0 Then`

Comment: Still giving me sheets not containing "-" :/ Edit: isn't it so odd that it can add INSIDE  the conditional XD

Comment: @user3561813  While what you said is true, VBA evaluates any non-zero numerical value as True. So the usagae of InStr() in OP's code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each ws In lastWB.Worksheets

    Set lastWS = ws
    lastName = lastWS.Name

    'if lastWG has "-", skip it.
    If InStr(1, lastName, "-") Then
        For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            'If the names match, move forward (any with a "-" will have already been skipped)
            If s.Name = lastName And s.Range("C3").Value <> "5860" Then
                Debug.Print lastName
                's.Range("C14:O48").Value = lastWS.Range("C14:O48").Value
            Else
                'If lastName does not have "-" and does not match the current sheet, log it
                skippedAct.Add lastName
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

This will log lastName for each sheet in thisworkbook that does not match. I am going to guess you only want to log it if it isn't found at all... so I would do this:

```
Dim logLast as Boolean
For Each ws In lastWB.Worksheets

    Set lastWS = ws
    lastName = lastWS.Name

    'if lastName has "-", skip it.
    If InStr(1, lastName, "-") Then
        LogLast = True
        For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            'If the names match, move forward (any with a "-" will have already been skipped)
            If s.Name = lastName And s.Range("C3").Value <> "5860" Then
                logLast = False                   
                Debug.Print lastName
                's.Range("C14:O48").Value = lastWS.Range("C14:O48").Value
            End If
        Next
        If logLast then skippedAct.Add lastName
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah but I want to see which sheets in lastWB is not in thisworkbook. Edit: hmm I guess s.name = lastName... maybe? I can't tell XD Edit2: nope this still fails :/

Comment: Updated. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `If InStr(1, lastWB, "-") Then` looks bad?

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the typo and added what I think you might be looking for.